# How to use 'require' to import a JSON in NestJS controller?

Tags: json, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to return a json file as a controller response, but I can't get the content of the json.

```js
import { Controller, Get, Res, HttpStatus, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

import * as MOCKED_RESPONSE_TS from './data/payment-method.data'; // this ts file is imported fine
const MOCKED_RESPONSE = require('./data/payment-method-mock'); // this json file is not found

@Controller('commons')
export class CommonController {

@Get('/payment-method')
  getPaymentMoethod(@Res() res: Response): any {
    res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(MOCKED_RESPONSE);
  }

}
```

> Actually the log returns: `Error: Cannot find module './data/payment-method'` and the app doesn't compile

I have done this with express (even with typescript) and works fine.

*I don't know if i have to setup my project to read jsons (I'm newby on nest). By the moment I have created a typescript file exporting a const with the json content and I called it successfuly*

Comment: What did you get?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. I guess the problem lies in the way you import your `.json` file (change import instead of const)
2. Another advice or solution would be to leverage the `.json()` method of the res object (which is actually the express adapter response object).

Let's try with this code:

### Your `common.controller.ts` file:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Res, HttpStatus, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

import * as MOCKED_RESPONSE_TS from './data/payment-method.data'; // this ts file should still be imported fine
import * as MOCKED_RESPONSE from './data/payment-method-mock.json'; // or use const inside the controller function

@Controller('commons')
export class CommonController {

@Get('/payment-method')
  getPaymentMoethod(@Res() res: Response): any {
    res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(MOCKED_RESPONSE); // <= this sends response data as json
  }
}
```

Also in your `tsconfig.json` file, don't forget to add this line:

### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other options 

    "resolveJsonModule": true, // here is the important line, this will help VSCode to autocomplete and suggest quick-fixes

    // ... other options
}
```

Last thoughts: you could use the `sendfile()` method of the `res` object depending on whether you want to send back a json ***file*** or the ***content*** of your json file.

Let me know if it helps ;)

Comment: This helped with the VSCode autocomplete, and then I got a VSCode about change import instead of const in the require function line... Thanks

Comment: I edited your answer, review it so I can pick it as solution

Comment: Why does `import * as MOCKED_RESPONSE from './data/payment-method-mock.json';` work but `import MOCKED_RESPONSE from './data/payment-method-mock.json';` doesnt?

Comment: @Seven because you would have to name and export `MOCKED_RESPONSE` object within `'./data/payment-method-mock.json'`, which is actually not possible in standard json.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you are calling it correctly.

Are you getting any response at all? if not double check your method name since its spelled like this: `getPaymentMoethod` and it should be this: `getPaymentMethod`.

Secondly I would recommend requiring outside the method and setting it to a constant.

Lastly try wrapping it in `JSON.stringify()` to convert the response to a json stringified object

Comment: I believe that in nest the name of controller function is just a for developer reference; I have a system error in the require node function and it breaks the flow :(

Comment: follow the second step of my comment. require outside of the function. it should be at the very top of the controller in the global state

Comment: Setting the require at the top of the file makes the app crash and doesn't compile... interesting